# Sql Server - Executing a stored procedure which takes input parameter of type BigIntList from the query editor window

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored proc which takes `@RegionIds` as a input parameter which is of type `BigIntList`.

It looks like below.

```
CREATE PROC @RegionTestProc
@RegionIds AS dbo.BigIntList
AS
BEGIN
/* SQL Query */
END
```

Now i have the `@RegionIds` values with me, lets say those values are [12,34,456,32,23,57],  I would like to execute this stored procedure from the Sql Server Management studio query editor window and see the ouput

```
EXEC @RegionTestProc @RegionIds = '12,34,456,32,23,57'
```

How do i pass the RegionIds to the stored proc ? the above query is throwing below error.

> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with BigIntList

Comment: your issue is youre trying to pass in a list of concatenated values into a proc that takes a table as a parameter.

Comment: I think that may be a user defined data type, defined in your local database.  Try to find it’s definition and show it to is.

Comment: @User19 see this basic article about it https://www.sqlshack.com/table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `BigIntList` is just a user defined table type with a column called `id` of type `BIGINT` (as the name implies):

```
DECLARE @RegiondIds BigIntList;
INSERT @RegionIds (id)
VALUES (12),(34),(456),(32),(23),(57);

EXEC @RegionTestProc @RegionIds = @RegionIds;
```